# Scrape website source and search for word

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I have this code for Python, but it searches for actual page and not the **source** of the page.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def count_words(url, the_word):
    r = requests.get(url, allow_redirects=False)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'lxml')
    words = soup.find(text=lambda text: text and the_word in text)
    print(words)
    return len(words)


def main():
    url = 'google.com'
    word = 'google'
    count = count_words(url, word)
    print('\nUrl: {}\ncontains {} occurrences of word: {}'.format(url, count, word))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

How do I make it to search for the page's source too?

I don't want to count. Yes, I know I have to remove the `count {}` part. But, how do I make it load a website list from a text file and if x word is found to print "X Found on this website"

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to search the source code for the occurrence of a certain substring, there is no need to use BeautifulSoup. It will only let you parse the actual page contents, and not including the source code.

Replace `count_words()` with the following code.

```
def count_words(url, the_word):
    r = requests.get(url).text    
    return r.count(the_word)

Output (do NOT include this in the final code):
>>> count_words('https://google.com', 'Google')
8
```

You just need to get the web page source code as a string using `requests`, and count the occurrences of a substring using `.count()`.

Also, make sure that you add a scheme (e.g. `http`, `https`) in your URL. Otherwise, BeautifulSoup will "freak" out.

Comment: import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
def count_words(url, the_word):
    r = requests.get(url).text    
    return r.count(the_word)

>>> count_words('https://google.com', 'Google')
8

def main():
    url = 'google.com'
    word = 'google'
    count = count_words(url, word)
    print('\nUrl: {}\ncontains {} occurrences of word: {}'.format(url, count, word))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()     This is final code?

Comment: No. Remove the `>>>` part. That's just to give you the output. Also, if you find that this answer solves your problem, we encourage you to click the green check mark on the left of this answer.

Comment: So all I have to do is remove the >>> and it will work? Thanks for your help man a lot.

Comment: All you need to do is replace your `count_words()` function with the one I have in your final code.

Comment: I clicked the tick? Is that right? And I am really lost right now.I don't know which part should be changed.Thanks!

Comment: Click the tick if you find this answers solves your problem.

Comment: I still need to know how can I implement it to be a fully working script haha

Comment: In your original code, you have the function `count_words()`. Replace your `count_words()` function body with the one I have in this answer.

Comment: So, your `count_words()` should be the same as mine.

Comment: Why did you include the code in lines 8 and 9? Those are just to show the output of the code.

Comment: Thanks! what about to load websites from a .txt? What function should I use?

Comment: That, I believe, would fit better as a separate question.

Comment: Sean, your modification worked for me, TQ